# IllegalArgumentException: unknown handler key at javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext.getContext

Tags: java, tomcat6, java-security

I am using Tomcat 6.0.44. I am getting exception :

> javax.security.auth.login.LoginException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown handler key at
>   javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext.getContext(PolicyContext.java:311)

at below line of code:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");
```

POM file where I have mentioned dependency is:

```
        <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.security.jacc</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.security.jacc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Do a PolicyContext.getHandlerKeys() to see if the handler for the specified key is in fact registered.

Comment: PolicyContext.getHandlerKeys()  is returning null and PolicyContext.getContextID() is also returning null. BUt my login is working fine. Whenever i write PolicyContext.getContext i am getting this error.